# Facebook Connect - Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, localization

I'm following the following tutorial for Facebook Connect:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

And attempting to allow my users to login via Facebook. Right now, I'm successfully rendering a permission request / login box, but the language, according to Google Translate, is Indonesian. I can see nowhere in my FB App settings to change this, and nowhere in the FB-Connect source to change this. I've tried not only my Inspire 4g, which has a custom ROM, but also a stock Galaxy Tab.

Has anyone encountered this before?

**EDIT:** Additionally, the app is attempting SSO (single-sign-on), aka, it's using the installed Facebook application to do the authorization, so I can't just tack on the locale to the end of the API URLs, as it's not using them. I will need to do that if the user doesn't have Facebook installed, but right now I'm trying to get SSO working.

Here is the relevant section of code from the FB API that calls the FB App. I imagine that somewhere within I need to request my specific locale:

```
private boolean startSingleSignOn( Activity activity, String applicationId, String[] permissions, int activityCode )
{
  boolean didSucceed = true;
  Intent intent = new Intent();

  intent.setClassName( "com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth" );
  intent.putExtra( "client_id", applicationId );

  /** perhaps here, I need to add to the Intent? **/

  if( permissions.length > 0 )
  {
    intent.putExtra( "scope", TextUtils.join( ",", permissions ) );
  }

  // Verify that the application whose package name is
  // com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth
  // has the expected FB app signature.
  if( !validateActivityIntent( activity, intent ) )
  {
    return false;
  }

  mAuthActivity = activity;
  mAuthPermissions = permissions;
  mAuthActivityCode = activityCode;
  try
  {
    activity.startActivityForResult( intent, activityCode );
  }
  catch( ActivityNotFoundException e )
  {
    didSucceed = false;
  }

  return didSucceed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Facebook:

[Facebook Authorize App dialog displayed using incorrect locale](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383)

Comment: I still don't see how to actually /do/ it though. I attempted to manually add the locale to the URLs in Facebook.java, but it's still in the incorrect language. Once I get that working, I can worry about having it automatically pull device settings. So, my question still stands, how do I actually specify locale with the Facebook-Connect-Android SDK?

Comment: @Josh: I see what you are saying.  Let me try something and hopefully post the correct solution shortly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm attempting to alert FB of the Repro, but their server is sending a 500 back when their AJAX POST happens. I guess I'll just wait and see.

Comment: This was indeed the issues, and Facebook has fixed the bug.